# Excluding lines, which are not containing one or multiple strings from text file

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, text, preprocessor, data-processing

I have multiple server log files. In total they contain around 500.000 lines of log text. I only want to keep the lines that contain "Downloaded" and "Log". Lines I want to exclude are focussing on error logs and basic system operations like "client startup", "client restart" and so on.

An example of the lines we are looking for is this one:

```
[22:29:05]: Downloaded 39 /SYSTEM/SAP logs from System-4, customer (000;838) from 21:28:51,705 to 21:29:04,671
```

The lines that are to be kept should be complemented by the date string, which is part of the log-file name. ($date)

Further, as the received logs are rather unstructured, the filtered files should be transformed into one csv-file (columns: timestamp, log downloads, system directory, system type, customer, start time, end time, date [to be added to every line from file name]. The replace operation of turning spaced into comma is just a first try to bring in some structure to the data. This file is supposed to be loaded into a python dashboard program.

At the moment it takes 2,5 mins to preprocess 3 Txt-Files, while the target is 5-10 seconds maximum, if even possible.

Thank you really much for your support, as I'm struggeling with this since Monday last week. Maybe powershell is not the best way to go? I'm open for any help!

At the moment I'm running this powershell script:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\AnonUser\RestLogs\*" -Include *.log

New-Item C:\Users\AnonUser\RestLogs\CleanedLogs.txt -ItemType file

foreach ($f in $files){

    $date = $f.BaseName.Substring(22,8)
    (Get-Content $f) | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'Downloaded' -and $_ -match 'SAP')} | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace " ", ","}{$_+ ','+ $date} | Add-Content CleanedLogs.txt
}
```

Comment: In the question you say that you _want to keep the lines that contain "Downloaded" and "Log"_, but in the code you filter for `Downloaded` and `AIM`. Please give us some more examples of the lines you want to keep and if possible an eaxmple of the file name where the $date part should be taken from.

Comment: It's ment to be filtered for SAP. Thank you, I just edited it the right way. Filename is something like this ```SAPlogsfiles0190701.log```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the fastest I could manage. I didn't test using `-split` vs `-replace` or special .NET methods:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\AnonUser\RestLogs\*" -Include *.log

New-Item C:\Users\AnonUser\RestLogs\CleanedLogs.txt -ItemType file

foreach ($f in $files) {

    $date = $f.BaseName.Substring(22,8)
    (((Get-Content $f) -match "Downloaded.*?SAP") -replace " ",",") -replace "$","$date" | add-content CleanedLogs.txt

}
```

In general, speed is gained by removing loops and `Where-Object` "filtering."

Comment: Thank you really much! The runtime reduced to 7-9 seconds.